# Insert JavaScripts into head of only one page

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to an SVGMap product that requires that I insert the following javascript into head but I only want to use this on one page of my website in a block. If I insert it into the html.tpl.php page, it will load for every page. Is this a drain on resources or is there a better way to do it for just the block that I need it?

Thanks

```
<link href="/mapsvg/css/mapsvg.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/mapsvg/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/mapsvg/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/mapsvg/js/mapsvg.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal provides theme suggestion for html.tpl.php

you can put html.tpl.php in templates folder inside you theme directory

**html--node--id.tpl.php**

***id*** will be your page id
e.g. ID = 123, then file name will be **html--node--123.tpl.php**

Hope this will help.

===================================================================

For particular block you can use **hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter**

@see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7.x

like,

```
function module_name_hook_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter(&$data, $block) {
  drupal_add_js();
}
```

Comment: Can I do this for a specific block and not a specific node?

Comment: For particular block overriding tpl is not a good option, Instead you can use hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I use the `hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter` hook? Would it be in a helper module?

Comment: Also, that first part of the code is a style sheet. Would I do that a different way?

Comment: You need to write hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter in custom module. for style sheet you can use drupal_add_css()

Answer (score 0):

Use [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) and [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) to dynamically add the files only when they're needed.

If you look at the scope option for drupal_add_js you can make sure the script tags are added in the header like you need

Comment: Where would I add these hooks? To my helper module? If so, how to I tell the helper module which block is going to use the js files?

Answer (score 0):

Include your scripts using drupal_add_js() in theme_preprocess_page() of your theme's template.php file.

```
    function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      if('page' === arg(0)) {
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/your_script1.js');
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/your_script2.js');
        ..
      }

      $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
    }
```

Comment: This would still add it to every page wouldn't it?

Comment: No, to ensure that we are checking the page arguments.
`if('page' === arg(0)) {
}`